# Client and Server connection fails around 4/5 of the time

Tags: java, android, sockets

For a while I now have been playing around with networking between my computer and my Android phone using Java both as the server and client app.

When connected, it works as it should, both ends sending and recieving as they should. However, I'm having trouble to make them always connect, even when on a LAN network, and the client usually times out when connecting, particularly when getting the ObjectInputStream.

I have tried increasing and decreasing the timeouts on both the client and server sockets without any better result. Only worse.

I'm not exactly certain what information anyone would need in order to give me such tips, so if I'm missing something from this text, please tell me and I'll provide what I have got.

I just would like some tips as to what may be wrong with my code or program flow that cause this problem. Is there problems with the timing of the connection? In that case, why does it work when I get the ObjectOutputStream from the socket?

In case it is of help, I've provided what I'd imagine is the most important parts of the connection classes on the bottom of the question post.

If this is questioned in the wrong way or just being too specific to my own project, please tell me and I'll remove the question and try again.

[ClientConnection.java](http://pastebin.com/zLqjLLk5) - The class handling all connection on the Android client.

[Server.java](http://pastebin.com/naKyMkFR) - Handles connecting clients and requests.

[Connection.java](http://pastebin.com/i7SyGK2V) - Currently just a storage class but will later also be used to check if the server should send a connection check and make sure the client is still connected.

Comment: Does the mobile device have a reliable connection to whatever network you're communicating over? Maybe you could test on a LAN if you're using whatever data network your provider has.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that detail. The computer I'm running the server on and the android device is connected to the same network and the Android device is using an internal IP when connecting.

Comment: Well, gotta Google a bit on what volatile actually means. Thanks for looking though.

Comment: Anytime you are using some object across multiple threads, you should be synchronizing the read/writes, with either volatile, atomic types, or with synch locks, using some object that is documented as thread safe.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll take a look at that as well then.

Comment: There are a number of places where you should be synchronizing your read writes. Like the connections collection in Server.java. Definitely take a look at some synchronization tutorials in java. It can be confusing, and everyone gets bit by concurrency problems, so try to eliminate those potential problem areas first, then see if your problem persists.